Supabase Auth Confirmation email tiggers duplicate processing of auth/confirm code
How do I prevent this code from running twice whenever email confirmation link sent by Supabase is clicked. (with the exception of the console.log lines this is straight from the supabase documentation for confirmation code.
enter image description here
This is the log results when email link is clicked.
enter image description here
I did remove the "async" for the function and the "await" for supabase.auth to force synchronous processing because second call was failing while first call was in process thus redirecting me to the error page instead of the home page. This at least allowed the success to redirect to the home page allowing me to continue forward.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
